# Request.Files is empty only in ie10 using xmlHttpRequst and ashx

Tags: c#, html, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-10, ashx

I am using HTML5 Drag&Drop File Upload with c# asp.net .
In all browsers everything work fine, but in IE10 I can't get the files in the server in order to save them.
I've tried everything and nothing works.
please help.

here is my code:

javascript & HTML:

```
function uploadFile(index) {
    var files = window.opener.files; //get the files from drag area which is in window.opener
    for (var i = index; i < (index + files.length); i++) {
       debugger;
       var size = fixSize(files.item(i - index).size);
       var name = files.item(i - index).name;
       xhr.push(new XMLHttpRequest()); //create new xhr and push it to xhr array
       //var form = window.opener.document.getElementById('ddform');
       //var data = new FormData(form);
       var data = new FormData();
       data.append("index", i);
       data.append("fileName", name);
       data.append("file", files.item(i - index));
       xhr[i].open('POST', "HandlerUploadFiles.ashx", true);
       xhr[i].send(data);
    }
}
```

ddform in opener window:

```
<form id="ddForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div id="drop_zone">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDragDrop" runat="server" Text="Drag File" style="color: #9A9A9A" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID='btnRefresh' runat="server" onclick="btnRefresh_Click" style="display:none" />
</form>
```

c#, using IHttpHandler:

```
public class HandlerUploadFiles : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       // context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
       string fileName = context.Request["fileName"];
       string postedFile = context.Request["file"]; // returns string : {"object file"}
       HttpFileCollection fileCollection = context.Request.Files; // always empty!!!
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have noticed when using IE10 or the latest chrome or ff, the `context.Request.Files` has 0 keys, but when you look in `context.Request`, the content length is there. I myself dont know how to get the file(s) from there. But in IE9 and down and other older browsers, the `context.Request.Files` has a length of 1+

Comment: Why are you sending each file in its own XHR? Just append all the files to your `FormData` instance in the for-loop and then send just one XHR.

Answer (score 0):

```
string _fileName = string.Empty;
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    try
    {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                if (file.ContentLength / 1024 < 1024 * 1) //1024*1 = 1 MB
                {
                    _fileName = file.FileName;
                    string fname =
                        context.Server.MapPath("~/tools/DragAndDropFileUpload/uploads/" +
                                               MyRandomChar.StringIntNumber(20) + Path.GetExtension(_fileName));
                    file.SaveAs(fname);
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Maximum file size exceeded.");

            }
            context.Response.Write("Uploaded Successfully!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```